# How to make GWT applications mobile compatible

Tags: gwt, mgwt

I have a website developed in GWT/MGWT

I used MGWT widgets, but when I run the application on my mobile everything is really small.
I don't think it's the matter of increasing width/height, etc.

You can open it on your mobile and have a look: `http://119.154.187.175:8080/dashboard2/dashboard2.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The viewport doesn't seem to be configured correctly. Try to set

```
MGWT.applySettings(MGWTSettings.getAppSetting());
```

in your entrypoint right at the beginning.

Here is also a getting started:
https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt/wiki/Getting-started-with-mgwt